# On Flat and Projective Modules over integral domain

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, projective-modules

Is this true that finitely generated flat module over an integral domain is projective.
If Yes, please provide a proof.

Comment: This follows immediately from Endo's theorem (i.e. a finitely generated flat module over a commutative ring is projective iff its tensor product with the total ring of fractions is projective).

Comment: @tj_ Endo, "On flat modules over commutative rings" (1962) refers to Cartier's 1958 paper for the requested result, in his first paragraph. In other words, he is generalising Cartier's statement.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, of course, one can directly refer to Cartier's paper. I personally prefer English references, because more people are familiar with English than with French.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Lemma 5 on page 249 of Cartier, "Questions de rationalité des diviseurs en géométrie algébrique" says that over an integral domain, whether or not it is Noetherian, if the localisation of a finitely generated module at every maximal ideal is free, then the module is projective. Over a local ring, every finitely generated flat module is free (see for example Matsumura, "Commutative Ring Theory" Theorem 7.10). Putting these together gives you a positive answer to your question.